# SVG Image linking

Tags: svg, hotlinking

I am trying to make my vector image clickable. I have searched the internet and can not find the answer. What else do I need in the code?

```
<div id="logo">  
<a href="http://fpmnky.com" target="_self">
<span>
    <object width="488" height="115" data="http://fpmnky.com/images/fpmlogo2.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
    <img width="488" height="115" src="http://fpmnky.com/images/fpmlogo2.svg" alt="Star"/>
        <span>Your browser doesn't support SVG images</span>
    </object>
</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id="logo">
<a href="http://fpmnky.com" target="_self">
    <img src="http://fpmnky.com/images/fpmlogo2.svg" width="488" height="115" alt="fpmlogo" />
</a>
```